# Basis for performing quantum measurement

Tags: quantum-information

What is the best basis for performing quantum tomography of qudits (for any dimension d) such that the measurement can by optimal in the sense of the quantity derived from the Fisher information of the experiment? How can I calculate such information from a particular arrange?

Comment: Any basis should be as good as any other, unless you know restrictions on the state of the qudits.

Comment: My restriction is the number of measurements, I would like to use SIC-POVM for performing quantum measurements such that I reduce the number of measurements, https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0405084v2.pdf , from this paper you can see how they deduce the best POVM for qubits, I wanna know what is the best basis for quantum systems of higher dimensions.

Comment: I don't think there is a *best basis* that would apply to all possible scenarios. You would probably need to model your specific case and then apply the Fisher information constraint to that case and optimize it.